# No menu when running openCV samples (Android Studio)

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, menu

Running openCV-Android samples does not work as expected. I have Android Studio on Windows, extracted OpenCV-Android 2.4.11 and the sample is tutorial-1-camerapreview (but other samples don't seem to work also)

If I use 'Import module' and run Tutorial1CameraView on a device, everything works fine. I have the 3 normal buttons [(link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPdkA.png) PLUS a 4th one, which opens a menu.

If I use 'New project' and do as if I coded it myself (copy/pasting the code and files from the tutorial), it runs the same app, but there is no 4th button. So I can't open the menu.

Here is exactly what I've done :

- New project -> blank activity
- Import the openCV libs ([I followed the instructions on this page](http://blog.hig.no/gtl/2014/08/28/opencv-and-android-studio/))
- Copy/paste the source code of Tutorial1CameraView in my MainActivity
- Merge the res folder from tutorial with res folder created by Android studio. I deleted some files, like the old menu folder
  (generated when I created the project, and not used by the tutorial),
  to be sure they don't interfere. (But it still doesn't work if I keep
  them)
- Renaming some trivial things like package/classes in the java and xml files to make it compile

if it helps, my java code is :

```
        import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
        import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
        import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
        import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
        import org.opencv.core.Mat;
        import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
        import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.SurfaceView;
        import android.view.WindowManager;
        import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private boolean              mIsJavaCamera = true;
    private MenuItem             mItemSwitchCamera = null;

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    public MainActivity() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1_surface_view);

        if (mIsJavaCamera)
            mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);
        else
            mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_native_surface_view);

        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);

        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreateOptionsMenu");
        mItemSwitchCamera = menu.add("Toggle Native/Java camera");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String toastMesage = new String();
        Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);

        if (item == mItemSwitchCamera) {
            mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.GONE);
            mIsJavaCamera = !mIsJavaCamera;

            if (mIsJavaCamera) {
                mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);
                toastMesage = "Java Camera";
            } else {
                mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_native_surface_view);
                toastMesage = "Native Camera";
            }

            mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
            mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, toastMesage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }
}
```

I can join any other files needed (It's probably not related to java ...)

What could be the problem ? Why does the app work but only the menu does not ?

Comment: "Renaming some trivial things like package/classes in the java and xml files to make it compile".. Have you changed the `theme` attribute of your activity in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: No, I didn't. I only changed really trivial things because some files/packages names differed.

The line in the manifest is :

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

What should I put instead ? And why would it change something, since it was also in the tutorial sample ?

Comment: Try removing the `.Fullscreen`

Comment: I think you're right. After reading your comment, I changed the apptheme and it worked. I'm testing removing just the "fullscreen". Would you like to write an answer, so I can mark it as solved ? Do you know why it worked when I imported module without having to rename it ?

Comment: I have posted an answer, but I am not sure why it would've worked initially.

Comment: It doesn't work when I remove the fullscreen thing (so the line is     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >) or when I remove NoTitleBar.
But it works when I put         android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" >
The interface is not the same than in the tutorial, but there is a menu button in the up-right corner. (But I'm OK with that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue, if the `theme` attribute for your activity in your AndroidManifest file ends in `.Fullscreen`, remove the `.Fullscreen`.

EDIT: Apparently removing the `.Fullscreen` doesn't work, however replacing the `theme` with one that does not have the `.Fullscreen`/`.NoActionBar` attributes. In this case `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"` did the trick.

Comment: That was the trick indeed. For some reason, the tutorial apptheme
@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen causes this bug. I don't know why it works when I import module.

I really had no idea what it could be (I read something about changing apptheme but didn't think it could be that ...) Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

delete android:theme="@style/Theme" in the manifest file.